# How to bind colors using a Custom Gradient Brush

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm having issues using a Custom Graident Brush named `AngleGradientBrush` to allow the drawning of a `Shape`.

To create this new `Gradient Brush` I used this: http://wpfkorea.tistory.com/169

It works perfectly great as I'm using only the code from `AngleGradientBrush.cs` to allow me to have a circular color for any Shape.

The problem is that, for a `LinearGradientBrush` or a `RadiantGradientBrush` it works if I do this:

```
            <Ellipse Name="FourDirectionsEllipse"
                       StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThiknessVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Width="{Binding ElementWidthVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Height="{Binding ElementHeightVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Opacity="{Binding OpacityFourDirectionsEllipseVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       IsEnabled="{Binding EnableFourDirectionsEllipseVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding DownColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.125"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding RightColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.125"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding RightColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding UpColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding UpColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.628"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding LeftColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.628"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding LeftColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.878"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding DownColorVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0.878"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Stroke>
            </Ellipse>
```

The color is binded without any problem, I can therefore change the colors of each `GradientStop`.

But if I use `<angleGradientBrushSample:AngleGradientBrush GradientDetail="1"> <GradientStop Color=...>...</angleGradientBrushSample:AngleGradientBrush>` instead the binding doesn't work.

I hope this is not a specific question for only my code but I thought it can help also when some people try to define a new `GradientBrush`.

Is the problem related to the code from the website I mentionned ? Do I need to add something so it handles the new colors ?

Comment: Just a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on all the Bindings is pointless. It has no effect at all.

Comment: Have you debugged into the AngleGradientBrush class to see whether its UpdateGradient() method is called when you update a Color Bindings's source property?

Comment: @Clemens It stays in the second for loop

Comment: @Clemens do you think that every time I set the property, I need to call a function from AngleGradientBrush ?

Comment: I don't think so, but I have no idea, sorry.